# I have installed "apiclient" to the spyder but why it gives the error "Module Not Found Error" when i run the program in Python

Tags: python

I am learning Social Media Analytics from Coursera. I am doing collecting data (YouTube API), I did everything shown in the video (from the Coursera) when I run the program in Python, it shows the following message:

```
File "C:\Users\Noor ul Aftab\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 8, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient'
```

How can i solve this problem?

I checked YouTube videos to solve the problem but the problem persists

Comment: There is no way of answering this without seeing the package structure. We are not familiar with the tutorial; don't assume that

Comment: the question appears to be not clear, would require specifics.

Comment: Show us exactly how you installed the module.

Comment: Have you installed the google api **pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you have `pip install apiclient`, check your `PATHONPATH` system environment variable. That variable should contain path to your `site-packages`. This being a Coursera related question you can try their dedicated forums too.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added the path but it still shows the error